# AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'destoryWindow'

Tags: python, opencv

Here is the code

```
img = cv2.imread('lena1.jpg')
b = img[:,:,0]
g = img[:,:,1]
r = img[:,:,2]
print(r.dtype)
emp = np.zeros(r.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("r", cv2.merge([emp, emp, r]))
if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
   print ("I'm done")
cv2.destoryWindow("r")
```

I can find the definition of destroyWindow in module cv2
[image]

Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Check the spelling of the method name. You spelled it wrong.

Comment: WOW! STUPID MISTAKE! Thanks.